# How to setup a google Optimize experiment that doesn't alter page layout?

Tags: google-optimize

I am new to Google Optimize A/B and multivariant test tools.

I am creating one experiment and noticed that I can/modify the look of the url I specify there. For example 50% of the traffic looks at variant a, the rest to b.

In my experiment I don't want to modify the page look, but instead I want to set for variant a a particular variable for example "groupA" and have my javascript code call a different API based on the group we belong.

Afterward the experiment result will monitor the conversion rate which is (nrPeopleClickingAButton / nrPeopleLandingOnThisPage).

Is there any way to achieve this?

How can I fetch the group name or experiement id or experiement name via Javascript in my code and let both variant a and b have exactly same look ?

I read one relevant article
https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9059383?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

but they don't explain

1. How I can get the experiement id for example for variant_a
2. How can I avoid the editor changes being applied to my variants. I don't want any page look change, I just want to inject different JS variable based on the group we belong then handle that myself in JS. That is all

Answer (score 0):

You can get the experiment_id here:

[image]

If you are using optimize.callback, with this code:

```js
function implementExperimentA(value) {
  if (value ==  '0') {
    // Provide code for visitors in the original.
  } else if (value == '1') {
    // Provide code for visitors in first variant.
  } else if (value == '2') {
    // Provide code for visitors in section variant.
  }
  ...
}
   
gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', {
    name: '<experiment_id_A>',
    callback: implementExperimentA
 });
```

You have to replace <experiment_id_A> with your Experiment ID (previous image), then in implementExperimentA function you have to change your page depending the variantion (0 - original, 1 - variant 1, 2 - variant 2...)

If you only want to change a variable and not to change the layout, you need to use "code editor" option and not make any more change, more info: [add global js](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6369964?hl=en&ref_topic=11611881#zippy=%2Ccode-editor%2Cadd-global-javascript-code)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see the "Code Editor" option. I click "Create Variant" and I can edit the html of that variant..

Comment: This is what I see, https://ibb.co/v3YNQ1k. If I click the "Edit" button I am redirected to the site and can change the html and design of the site.

Comment: I can use the code editor inside the Edit button as well, but this is going to return the custom html with modified JS to the customer and it is not what I want to do. The html is rendered server side and don't want google optimize to cache or do any change to it. I am wondering if they have some functionality like for example Dynamic Yield that inject javascript on top of whatever I load, or at least let me know about the user group and don't mess with the design at all

Comment: I also do not understand why there are 3 values in the `implementExperimentA` function above for a a/b test with only 2 groups. 0 = original group, 1 = the other 50%. What about value 2 then...

Comment: Hi @KristiJorgji! this code is an example, you can modify it as you need, in your case you need to remove the code that check variant 2. In Google Optimize you can not add code out of the variant, but if you only need to know the variant you can check it with the implementExperimentA function